# How to force ALL programs to use my Proxy?

Tags: proxy, tunneling

I have a local proxy on my PC. (localhost:8888)
But unfortunately there are many programs which are not able to go through this proxy.
So how can I force all my programs to go through my local proxy (or tunnel my connections to my local proxy)?

So all the programs on my PC could go through this proxy before reaching the internet!!?

Comment: what kind of a proxy do you have on localhost:8888? ssh, vpn, tor? and also, are you using windows, linux, macos?

Comment: @pootzko default port for Fiddler so that would be my guess

Comment: use proxifier or else try proxy cap

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you considered using a [transparent proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server#Transparent_proxy)?  It can automatically intercept all traffic and feed it to the proxy.

If you're asking about Tor, check out the [Tor transparent proxy](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy), which might do exactly what you want.  You might also check out [Torouter](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/Torouter).

Comment: do you have any suggestions for a transparent proxy (application?)

Comment: squid proxy with a linux firewall redirect rule, but thats not a single application nor a windows solution...

Comment: Okay, thanks - i found an application named: [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/)

Comment: proxiCap works pretty well and is cross platform

Answer (score 1):

If this is important enough and firewall/driver solutions are not working - you can make the only internet gateway available to the computer be *another* computer that runs the desired proxy.

You can enforce this in one of two general ways:

- Configure your home router to whitelist only the proxy computer's MAC for outgoing traffic from the LAN.
- Have two NIC cards on the computer running the proxy and connect the other computer directly to the second NIC card. The proxy computer has full control over what bridges between the two LANs, if correctly configured.